# Training data set for food image recognition

Tags: neural-network, dataset, image-classification, image-recognition

There are many excellent posts and answers referencing data sources. However I can't seem to find many for food image/photograph recognition. I would have thought, with so many people taking and uploading pictures of their food, that this should be readily available. Can anyone help? Food101 and UEC are good but limited. Thank you.

Comment: I presume you know the FOOD-256

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Food 101 dataset](https://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/datasets_extra/food-101/) or 
[UEC Food 256](http://foodcam.mobi/dataset256.html), both contains real-world food images.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Pittsburgh Fast Food Dataset http://pfid.rit.albany.edu/
You might find it limited, but you can join it with the other available datasets.